# How to create an infinite floor (skyline) in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

**QUESTION:**

So I came across this:

https://skin-tracker.com/pubg/outfit?no=000000000000000000000000000&set=1&char=1

I have the central ground area which is textured already in my code. But I have no idea how to make it extend up to the horizon like seen in the link.

It seems the person who coded what you see in the link hit some kind of limitation and had to use a single color for what extends beyond the central floor area.

How can I make my floor extend to the horizon/ create a skyline ?

---

**CODE:**

```
var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '../../public/assets/grassTile.jpg' );
floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
floorTexture.repeat.set( 10, 10 );
var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000, 10, 10);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
mesh.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add( mesh );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply create an enormous textured plane. I found no limitations with the example below. If you implement something like this and encounter errors/problems, update your question with the errors you're seeing.

```js
// prepare the renderer

let WIDTH
let HEIGHT
let aspectRatio = function() {
  return WIDTH / HEIGHT
}

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true
})
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(32, aspectRatio(), 1, 1000)
camera.position.set(0, 10, 50)

function resize() {
  WIDTH = window.innerWidth
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
  camera.aspect = aspectRatio()
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
}
resize()

window.addEventListener("resize", resize)

const scene = new THREE.Scene()

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity)
light.position.set(0, 0, 1)
camera.add(light)

scene.add(camera)

const sun = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffcc)
sun.position.set(0, 1, 0)
scene.add(sun)

// populate the scene

let geo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10)
let mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: "red"
})
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat)
scene.add(mesh)

let tex = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Grass_Texture.png")
tex.anisotropy = 32
tex.repeat.set(100, 100)
tex.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
tex.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping
geo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(10000, 10000)
mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  map: tex
})
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat)
mesh.position.set(0, -5, 0)
mesh.rotation.set(Math.PI / -2, 0, 0)
scene.add(mesh)


let axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0)
function updateCamera() {
  camera.position.applyAxisAngle(axis, 0.01)
}

// rendering functions

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
  camera.lookAt(scene.position)
}

let animationLoopId = null

function animationLoop() {
  animationLoopId = requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop)
  updateCamera()
  render()
}

animationLoop()
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: skyBLue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/97/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have one limitation/issue with this approach: how can I prevent the user from rotating the scene to see below the plane ? (I am using Orbitcontrols)

Comment: That will depend on your mouse controller. For example, the `OrbitControls` example can set a maximum/minimum elevation angle ([`maxPolarAngle`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls.maxPolarAngle)/[`minPolarAngle`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls.minPolarAngle))

Comment: All right. One last thing: when applying the texture to the ground, it appears much lighter (color) in three.js than it really is. It seems you did not have this issue with your example. Do you have the same issue with this texture ? https://www.textures.com/download/grass0130/38953?q=grass+tile

Comment: I had accidentally added a color to the plane. I've updated my code to use the raw texture. You can tweak the overall "darkness" of the texture by applying a gray-scale `color`. For example, if I add `color: 0x555555` to the material definition, the texture becomes darker because it blends with the underlying color.

Comment: Strange, in my case, the texture becomes immediately way too saturated even when I pick more "balanced" colors. Regardless, you answered my question : thank you :D